# I downvote because UI

Tags: script, comments, voting

## An integration of the [idownvotedbecau.se](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) website

I made a userscript which adds a simple popup whenever you are downvoting a question, which lets you choose from a set of reasons on why you did it.

### How it works?

When you hit the downvote button on a question the following popup will show.

[image]

After you have chosen from any option, the userscript will add a comment under the post which will look something like the following:

*I downvoted, because it seems like that [no or less effort in debugging the code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) was made.*

### But why?

I really like the website and IMO it is really important to justify the reason of downvoting a question, especially for new users. Anyhow me being pretty lazy, I never really bother to search for the proper link and everything.

### Installing

1. Install any free userscript manager, such as [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) for Chromium and Firefox based browsers.
2. Install the userscript by clicking [`here`](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/IDownvotedBecauseUI/raw/master/src/core.user.js).
3. Now the next time you will click the downvote button, the pop up shown above will appear.

### Issues and feedback

If there are any problems with the userscript, or anything else that should be discussed in more detail, head over to the [Github repository](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/IDownvotedBecauseUI) where the source code can be found and create an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am against this idea and I don't suggest installing this userscript.

[**idownvotedbecau.se is not something you should use in the comments**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379603) and whoever violates this rule is most likely going to be suspended. Also note that if a user flags these comments as NLN, they will be automatically deleted by Community.

My suggestion would be **to remove** the link and instead add your own text.

Comment: That seems to be a fair statement and Improvement, although I only partially agree. Anyhow since v2.0 it is way easier to customize those messages yourself, but I will defiantly add an easier way for custom reasons as well. Thanks for the suggestion! Also I am going to improve the way this popup will get displayed to the downvoter. I totally agree that you shouldn't leave a reason every time you are downvoting something, therefor just hitting ESC or similar will result in no reason at all. Although I am trying to improve this behavior in the future.

Comment: I don't believe the link you provided provides much in the way against using idownvotedbecau.se. Users are not blindly suspended for using a link to it--context is key.

Comment: From the link "**If you're caught using these links pejoratively** in an attempt to couch an outright insult in a manner where you think you can hide behind "just trying to help", you're very likely going to be suspended."